# AngularJS 1.5 + Yii2 REST. Не удается выполнить POST-запрос

Tags: javascript, angularjs, yii2, rest

Метод API который я вызываю:

```
public function actionCreate()
    {
        $request  = Yii::$app->request;
        $resource = $request->post('resource');
        $sourceId = $request->post('sid');

        if ($resource && $sourceId) {
            // Код
        } else {
            // Получаю это сообщение
            throw new HttpException(400, "Check parameters 'resource' (value: $resource) or 'sid' (value: $sourceId)"); 
        }
    }
```

И код на Angular'e, который я пытаюсь вызвать:

```
var post = function(method, data) {
    var requestParams = {
        url: 'api/method',
        method: 'POST',
        data: {
            'resource': 'asdasd',
            'sid': 123
        },
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/javascript; charset=UTF-8'
            //'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8' 
        }
    };
    return $http(requestParams);
};

var useSource = function(source) {
    post('sources', {
        'resource': source.resourceId,
        'sid': source.id
    }).then(function(response) {
        console.log('success');
        console.log(response);
    }, function error(response) {
        console.log('error');
        console.log(response);
    });
}
```

Всегда получаю вот такую ошибку:

> Check parameters 'resource' (value: ) or 'sid' (value: )

Как будто бы, я не указываю параметры при запросе в ангуляре.

В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: проверь что именно у тебя отправляется, есть ли в запросе эти параметры, например на вкладке Network(Сеть) браузера

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте посмотреть данные в теле запроса

```
$post = file_get_contents('php://input');
```

Еще, если запрашиваете данные кроссдоменно(поддомен, другой домен), нужно настроить yii2 контроллер или экшн для принятия таких данных.